# passing jquery var from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery

This is in script `.ready()` function which fetch existing files from database and putting in jquery var `splitfiles`. which is in array formate.

```
  var splitfiles = '<?php echo @$projectDetails->upload_file; ?>';
```

this line gives array of attached file from view in controller

```
 $arrayoffiles = json_encode($joinfiles);
```

I want to get  this `splitfiles` var in controller and then merge with  `$arrayoffiles` after that store in database with other form data.

I tried with this solution to pass 'splitfiles' to controller by this bellow code but i am not getting in the controller

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo site_url("trusts/fundsRaisingModule"); ?>',                       
    type: 'GET',  
    dataType: 'json',   

    data: {
        splitfiles:splitfiles,
        // key : value pair. You can send as many pair as you want like this
    }

   });
 });
```

In controller i am not getting the 'splitfiles'

```
    $files=$_REQUEST['splitfiles'];
```

giving error :undefined index 'splitfiles'
so help me to pass jquery variable from view to controller in codeigniter
after that i will try to merge the two arrays
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what isnt working?

Comment: @ Freeman Lambda , I tried bellow solution in the beginning only In controller i am not getting   'splitfiles' it is giving undefined index error

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this use jquery `ajax()` and send the js variable to controller method and use it as you want.

Its syntax is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'controller_method',                        
        type: 'POST',                                  
        data: {
            splitfiles  :splitfiles,
            // key : value pair. You can send as many pair as you want like this
        },
        success: function(response){    // response from process
            // do your stuff here
        }
    });
});
```

controller_method

```
$splitfiles = $_REQUEST['splitfiles'];
// do your stuff here
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add the jquery library in your code.

Comment: on sucess i dont want to do anything

Answer (score -1):

First send that jQuery variable into any hidden input of the view, and then get that input value into controller through GET or POST method.